# Prints letter pattern with certain amount of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help fixing my code, see below for problem.

I have to write a function that prints out the L shape made up of *'s. Also, the parameter M is an integer between 1 and 80 and is the rows of the shape. The output needs to be N rows, the last of which should comprise N letters of L.
My user input should be the desired rows but its just printing the range, and even that looks a little off. Please assist, if you can... this is what I have so far:

```
M = int(input())
def solution(M):
    result =""
    if M > 80:
        for row in range(1, 80):
            for column in range(1, 80):
                if (column == 1 or (row == 1 and column != 0 and column < 1)):
                    result = result + "*"
                else:
                    result = result + "\n"
    print(result)
solution(M)
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input and output

Comment: How could M ever be greater than 80 if M is always between 1 and 80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just printing * for each row, unless the row = M in which case it is printing "*" * M and exiting if the value is >= 80 or <= 1 (since you said between 1-80):

```
import sys
print("Please enter an integer between 1-80:")
M = int(input())

def solution(N):
    if N >= 80 or N <= 1:
        sys.exit("Please run again using an integer between 1-80")
    result = ""
    for row in range(1, N+1):
        if row < N:
            result = "*"
            print(result)
        elif row == N:
            result = "*" * N
            print(result)
solution(M)
```

Then when you run:

```
[dkennetz@nodecn001  tmp]$ python3 fun.py
Please enter an integer between 1-80:
4
*
*
*
****
```

Comment: Thank you so much this makes perfect sense!

Comment: If this worked for you, please click the checkmark under the vote to accept it as an answer so future visitors to the question see this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```py
M = int(input())
def solution(M):    
    result_str=""
    for row in range(0,M+1):    
        for column in range(0,M+1):     
            if (column == 1 or (row == M and column != 0 and column < M)):  
                result_str=result_str+"*"    
            else:      
                result_str=result_str+" "    
        result_str=result_str+"\n"    
    print(result_str)
solution(M)
```

https://ideone.com/UoGj2n

https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-conditional-exercise-21.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this solution. I hope that it's clear enough:

```
SYMBOL = '*'

def solution(M, N):
  result = []

  # validations
  if M > 80:
    M = 80
  if N > 80:
    N = 80

  for row in range(1, M + 1):
    if row < M:
      result.append(SYMBOL)
    else:
      # last row
      result.append(''.join([SYMBOL for column in range(1, N + 1)]))

  return result

# generate rows
result = solution(10, 5) # TODO: use values from input() instead
# print result
for row in result:
  print(row)
```